# Spring for Hadoop: issues with batch-spark sample on CDH 5.8

Tags: spring, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to run

https://github.com/trisberg/springone-2015/tree/master/batch-spark

on Cloudera Hadoop 5.8 ( quickstart ). I followed this guide in order to try to setup everything:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html

I fixed all the versions related to:

- spark assembly to upload to HDFS is *spark-assembly_2.10-1.6.0-cdh5.8.0.jar*;
- moved the property *spring-data-hadoop.version* in pom.xml to version 2.4.0.RELEASE-cdh5;
- moved the property *spark.version* in pom.xml to 1.6.

I was able to build the project, upload the built artifact on CDH 5.8 quickstart's VM but, when trying to RUN, the batch fails.

When checking the log on Cloudera Manager I see the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 6 more

I tried to submit the Spark Job through the following command

- sudo -u hdfs spark-submit --class Hashtags --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster app/spark-hashtags_2.10-0.1.0.jar hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/hashtags/input/tweets.dat hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/hashtags/output*

( simulating the hdfs scripts to prepare input and output folders by hand )

and everything worked perfectly.

I was able to check the Resource Manager's logs in order to find any difference between the launching command produced by the Spring Batch's tasklet and the spark-submit command and I found that:

- spark-submit puts the following:

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher:
>   Command to launch container container_1486926591393_0015_02_000001 :
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH",{{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java,-server,-Xmx1024m,-Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp,-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=,-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster,--class,'Hashtags',--jar,file:/home/cloudera/spring-batch-spark/app/spark-hashtags_2.10-0.1.0.jar,--arg,'/tmp/hashtags/input/tweets.dat',--arg,'/tmp/hashtags/output',--executor-memory,1024m,--executor-cores,1,--properties-file,{{PWD}}/**spark_conf**/**spark_conf**.properties,1>,/stdout,2>,/stderr

- Spring Batch's tasklet generates the following:

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher:
>   Command to launch container container_1486833100526_0006_01_000001 :
>   {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java,-server,-Xmx1024m,-Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp,-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=,-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster,--class,'Hashtags',--jar,file:/home/cloudera/spring-batch-spark/app/spark-hashtags_2.10-0.1.0.jar,--arg,'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/hashtags/input/tweets.dat',--arg,'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/hashtags/output',--executor-memory,1024m,--executor-cores,1,--properties-file,{{PWD}}/**spark_conf**/**spark_conf**.properties,1>,/stdout,2>,/stderr

**As you can see spark-submit adds LD_LIBRARY_PATH while Spring Batch's tasklet doesn't** and since it seems it is the only different thing I'm thinking that the problem is there.

Due to my poor knowledge of the topic I'm not able to understand what is going on under the hoods.
Did any of you run into this issue?

Thanks to everybody.
Guido

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed comparison. I don't think the LD_LIBRARY_PATH would cause this particular error, I wonder if the difference in the `--arg` values have any impact. For the spark-submit example you used `/tmp` vs `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/` for the spring-hadoop one. Could you try the spark-submit with `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/` prefix?

UPDATE: It looks like the Cloudera provided assembly jar 'spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.8.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.8.0.jar' is missing the Hadoop configuration classes and can not be used with the "spring-data-hadoop-spark" features. You have to use the complete assembly jar provided by the Spark project in their downloads. I tested with 'spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar' and it worked fine on the Cloudera QuickStart VM 5.8.

Comment: thank you so much and sorry for my mistake. Actually I run the _spark-submit_ command like you suggested ( `sudo -u hdfs spark-submit --class Hashtags --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster app/spark-hashtags_2.10-0.1.0.jar hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/hashtags/input/tweets.dat hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/demo/hashtags/output` ) and it works: the job fails when launched from Spring Batch's tasklet, due to the stack trace reported on my initial post

Comment: I'll see if I can run it on my machine against the Cloudera QuickStart VM, I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: I'll appreciate a lot, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I was able to run the example against CDH 5.8 Quickstart!!! I basically had to create the class `com.springdeveloper.demo.EnhancedSparkYarnTasklet` as a clone of `org.springframework.data.hadoop.batch.spark.SparkYarnTasklet` and enriching the instance of  `org.apache.spark.SparkConf` assigning  both properties `spark.executor.extraClassPath` and `spark.driver.extraClassPath` the value `/usr/lib/hadoop/client/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar`. Do you think there's a best way to do it?

Comment: It's definitely a classpath issue, I know we've had to add various classpath setting or different distros, maybe adding some hadoop config files could help. I would have to experiment to see what works. We've added a distro specific hadoop-site.xml file to get some mapreduce jobs to run on YARN - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-samples/blob/master/hadoop-config/cdh5/hadoop-site.xml

Comment: thanks for your feedback and you precious help. Exactly my same result. The fact is that checking YARN configuration on Cloudera Manager I saw that the property `yarn.application.classpath` is already set similarly to the one shown on the link you posted...it seems like the property is not propagated to the context ( I don't know if it is the right term ) of the Spark Job launched through the Client used in SparkYarnTasklet implementation...

Comment: Hi Thomas, did you succeed in the attempts you reported in your last comment?

Comment: Sorry, not yet, trying to get some time for it later this week.

Comment: I just tried this on a Cloudera QuickStart VM configured with a host-only network adapter so I can access Hadoop from my local system. I also used the 'spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop.2.6.0.jar' from the regular Spark distribution. After updating the dependency versions and building the app it ran fine against the Cloudera QuickStart Hadoop cluster.

Comment: I just tried again using 'spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.8.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.8.0.jar' and I do get that same 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration'. Not sure what they changed for the Cloudera distribution but it seems that the plain vanilla Spark assembly works better for our code.

Comment: wow! Thanks for these feedbacks. Could you confirm that you didn't need to pass any "extraClasspath" properties in `SparkConf` while running with `spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop.2.6.0.jar`?

Comment: I did not add any extra classpath setting when using `spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop.2.6.0.jar`, that jar file contains the hadoop classes while the Cloudera one doesn't. So when running with the Cloudera provided one we need those extra classpath settings you discovered. We might want to add those as properties (spark.executor.extraClassPath and spark.driver.extraClassPath) to the tasklet configuration - could you add an issue for this here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHDP

Comment: Thank you so much for the time spent for this issue and for the precious support you gave me. Following your suggestion I just created this Jira issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHDP-582